# Stripe Onboarding and external accounts

Tags: stripe-payments

I am using Stripe Onboarding on my marketplace to ease the process of getting my customers info (custom accounts). But it does not ask the user his external (bank) account information so payouts stay disabled. Is it normal ?

I am using:

```
  type: 'custom_account_verification',
  collect: 'eventually_due',
```

using the other type does not change anything

Comment: Stripe does not collect bank account details on the hosted onboarding page today. This information needs to be collected separately on your website instead.

Comment: So it is normal, thank you. I need an answer to accept ;)

Comment: Well, if it is not provided by Onboarding, I can do it by hand and using their API.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Stripe does not collect external account information (bank account or debit card) today in the Hosted Onboarding page. They focus on collecting personal information about the owner(s) of the account/company.

Today, you need to collect this information separately on your website. The easiest solution is to collect bank account details and tokenize this client-side with [Stripe.js](https://stripe.com/docs/js/tokens_sources/create_token?type=bank_account) and then create an external account server-side via the [API](https://stripe.com/docs/api/external_account_bank_accounts/create).

Answer (score 1):

This is now supported in hosted onboarding by enabling this toggle in the Stripe dashboard: https://dashboard.stripe.com/settings/connect/payouts/onboarding

Answer (score 0):

Just for reference Stripe is partnering with Plaid for this.

https://stripe.com/docs/ach#using-plaid

https://plaid.com/docs/stripe/